# How to send a test using mailchimp that wont ignore mergetags?

Tags: email, testing, send, mailchimp, newsletter

I have a issue with mailchimp,

When i send the campaign, everything works. Also when I preview using header info,

But If I sent a test, then the mergetags are ignored (and so are my conditions)

Is there a way to send a test like a campaign is sent? right now I am sending a copy of the campaign as a test, but its really not the plan (sometimes I need to send more than 10 test for a campaign),

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of an option to actually send a test email with filled mergetags, but you can try using Preview mode as described [here](http://kb.mailchimp.com/article/how-do-i-preview-a-campaign-before-i-send-it#preview).

Basically it allows you to simulate how an email will look like by injecting one of the users on your list.

Comment: Yes, but I cannot share it with others (designers, customers, ... )

Comment: I understand. Well, I cannot find another way. Perhaps you could do that with their public API.